# Running some Cucumber steps without invoking Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, cucumber-jvm

Scenario

```
Step1 Run 1 webservice
Step2 Validate stepService
Step3 initiate browser/visit url
```

Is there a possibility to have Step 1 and 2 not to call for Webdriver?
My understanding if I do not force step to call anything like visit url, then I should be fine
Reason for asking I have Cucumber JVM framework and trying to implement some web service calls before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the step definitions for Step 1 and Step 2, you can perform non-Webdriver/non-UI tasks as well. Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Comment: thank for confirming, also would it be possible to have complete scenario of some calculations with webservice calls without calling Webdriver, again none of step actually require browser

Comment: Yes, it is possible to implement a scenario using Cucumber and Java that contains no UI based activities.

Comment: that will not require any changes to the existing framework?

Comment: Depends on how the existing framework has been designed. However, if you create a new feature file having the UI independent scenario and implement its steps in a new step definition file, no changes should be required.

Comment: what I meant unless my step do not require lets say Chromedriver, steps will be executed and framework will not try to create webdriver instance

Comment: If your step does not require ChromeDriver, then in the Step definition file you do not need to create a Webdriver instance.

Comment: May be to verify this, you can just put `System.out.println();` statements in your step definitions for a UI independent scenario and see how it executes.